# Gif animation freeze in mac safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I am working on this site "http://tinyurl.com/joblnmd". On home page there'gif animation, I've used preload method to load images, its working on all major browsers expect safari on Mac.

Is this bug in safari or is there any hack?

Comment: Can you repeat this problem using a reduced amount of code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: May be feature as documented in this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16177

Answer (score 0):

New Post: I've looked at the site again and there doesn't seem to be any problems. The loading hourglass appears for a long time, but it eventually disappears and the main content of the page is visible. It might be best for your to provide a JSFiddle with just the area in question so that I, or someone else, can have a proper look and help you solve your problem.

---

Old Post: Maybe you need to update your browser. My Mac Safari appears to show everything perfectly. But I'll check again later tonight. The animation looks very nice.